# Include Cache in Magento2 module with using block

Tags: javascript, html

I have a block where I use as a slider in my home page, but it is not curling and I need it to do.

The module I use is the **Slider**.

**Would there be a way for me to force caching the module?**

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to go in the XML File and set the attribute as Cacheable True.

For Ex:

```
<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**For implement cache for block, you need define `cache_lifetime`.**

```
<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="cache_lifetime" xsi:type="number">864000</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Also, you can add cache key if you will feel.